# On functions similar to Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: special-functions, zeta-functions, analytic-number-theory

Denoted as $\zeta(s,a)$ for a > 0

> Where do I find topics on the Hurwitz zeta function for a < 0?

Any links or resources would be appreciated.
(Please dont mention wiki or mathworld)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11) and the [Wolfram Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta2/) site... which people really should be checking out first when they encounter an unfamiliar "special function".

Comment: I had already checked those sites (they come up in google)... But thanks anyways :) It will be useful for people who do not know it... +1

Comment: @rpg: Well, any search for properties of Hurwitz ζ would be well-served by also looking at the more general Lerch Φ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple connection between $\zeta(s,a)$ when $a$ is negative vs when $a$ is positive.

First you need to know that $\zeta(s,a)$ is undefined when $a$ is a negative integer.  This is because then $(n+a)^{-1}$ can be undefined when $n=-a.$  So you must let $a$ be not an integer.

If you do that, we can then use an identity: $\zeta(s,a)= \frac{1}{a} + \zeta(s,a+1)$ which holds by analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}\setminus{1}.$  By using this repeatedly, we can eventually shift the zeta function to a positive value.